# Admob GADBannerView.m bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool) iOS iPhone crash

Tags: multithreading, ios, uikit, crash, admob

I running the app on iPhone 3.1.3 (first gen iPhone) with admob sdk.  Thought not all the time, I started to get this error lately, which I never seen before.

```
<Warning>: bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x3c3840: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
```

and then when I trace the error down in the log file,  I see

```
Thread 6 Crashed:
0   WebCore                         0x00084380 _WebTryThreadLock(bool) + 288
1   WebCore                         0x00084ac0 _WebThreadAutoLock() + 52
2   UIKit                           0x0022061c -[UIWebView dealloc] + 128
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0003963a -[NSObject release] + 28
4   UIKit                           0x0000ab2c -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 592
5   UIKit                           0x0005ca1c -[UIView dealloc] + 232
6   My iPhone App                       0x0008d4e0 0x1000 + 574688
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0003963a -[NSObject release] + 28
8   UIKit                           0x0000ab2c -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 592
9   UIKit                           0x0005ca1c -[UIView dealloc] + 232
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0003963a -[NSObject release] + 28
11  UIKit                           0x000cad5c -[UIViewController dealloc] + 188
12  My iPhone App                       0x00015e60 0x1000 + 85600
13  My iPhone App                       0x000135c4 0x1000 + 75204
```

and traced it down even further and got,

```
-[GADBannerView dealloc] (in My iPhone App) (GADBannerView.m:111)

-[myViewController dealloc] (in My iPhone App) (myViewController.m:378)

-[mySubViewController dealloc] (in My iPhone App) (mySubViewController.m:64)
```

I have no idea what's going on.  Is there something I can do to prevent the crash or is this something admob has to fix?

Any help is apprecated

Answer (score 0):

Try debugger to get the idea where your error occurred. Also from where you are calling removeFromSuperView method. This might be causing the problem